# Google Maps: Some KMZ layers disappear after many access

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml, layer, invalidation

Recently I'm developping a Map containing KML Layer compressed as KMZ file (about 45mb).
As there is a file weight limitation, I first split the files into 3mb files.
Then I noticed that some splitted files was not showing everytime, causing some "blanks" on the map.
So I made researches on many forums, and found that the real limitation of files in order to get everything working properly is 2mb.
After update, the KML Layer was indeed showing entierely.

However, after doing many tests, I seen that some parts was disappearing again.
Currently there about half of parts that are not showing, like they were rejected by Google Maps API (the rejected parts are always the same, and they are not increasing so I think they are not valid).
I did again many research on Google Maps KML Layer API and limitations/validation but couldnt find any information that match with my problem.

Google Maps API does not send error, just got null response like:

```
/**/_xdc_._swjxb2 && _xdc_._swjxb2( [0,null,null,null,null,null,4,[["client","2"]]] )
```

Does anyone knows the rules about files limitation/validation ?
Is there a limit of access for one KMZ URL ? Or it is because the file is invalid ? If so, how to check if my file is valid ?

Here is the KML extracted from one of the KML files that are rejected:

DOWNLOAD URL: https://mega.nz/#!zohkmSAQ

KEY: !4HfbSLDpazhXHsTpFLOgfgXirRbt2usNFVy-ZYoDNcw

For some reasons, I only removed code that was inside .
But here is its format:

```
<![CDATA[<html xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<table>
<td>NAME</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table>
<tr>
<td>LABEL</td>
<td>VALUE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>LABEL</td>
<td>VALUE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>LABEL</td>
<td>VALUE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>LABEL</td>
<td>VALUE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>LABEL</td>
<td>VALUE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>LABEL</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>LABEL</td>
<td>VALUE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>LABEL</td>
<td>VALUE</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>]]>
```

I tried to rename extension as xml and open it with Chrome to check if it is well formated, but it was properly parsed by Chrome.

EDIT: Problem was solved by upgrading server for KMZ file upload.

Answer (score 1):

[KML Restrictions from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#restrictions)

> **Size and complexity restrictions for KML rendering**
>   The Maps JavaScript API has limitations to the size and complexity of loaded KML files. Below is a summary of the current limits.
>
> Note: These limits are subject to change at any time.

```
Maximum fetched file size (raw KML, raw GeoRSS, or compressed KMZ)          3MB

Maximum uncompressed KML file size                                         10MB

Maximum number of network Links                                              10

Maximum number of total document-wide features                            1,000
```

> **Number of KML layers**
>          There is a limit on the number of KML Layers that can be displayed on a single Google Map. If you exceed this limit, none of your layers will appear on the map, and an error will be reported in your web browser's JavaScript console. The limit is based on a combination of the number of KmlLayer classes created and the total length of all the URLs used to create those layers. Each new KmlLayer you create will take up a portion of the limit for the layer and a further portion of the limit depending on the length of the URL where the KML file was loaded from. Consequently, the number of layers you can add will vary by application; on average, you should be able to load between 10 and 20 layers without hitting the limit. If you still hit the limit, use a URL shortener to shorten the KML URLs. Alternatively, create a single KML file consisting of NetworkLinks to the individual KML URLs.

The KML you posted is 5MB (which exceeds the maximum fetched file size).

[Gives FETCH_ERROR](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linkToB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/SO_20190827_doc.kml)

[But can be loaded with the third party library geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/SO_20190827_doc.kml) (but as that translates it into "normal" google maps objects in the browser, performance may suffer)

[Zipped (KMZ) still gives me a FETCH_ERROR](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linkToB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/SO_20190827_doc.zip)

[still loads with geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/SO_20190827_doc.kmz)

Comment: The KML I posted is not a fetched file but uncompressed KML file.
So as maximum is 10MB it should be ok isn'it ?
By the way, files that are not rejected has exactly same weight.

When compressed as KMZ, the file is 1,9 mb.

Comment: Do you mean that the compressed KMZ file AND the KML file included inside should be BOTH maximum 3MB ?

Comment: No.  The "Maximum uncompressed KML file size" is 10MB.  But I still get a `FETCH_ERROR` if I zip the posted file to kmz.

Comment: I see, the problem is that if I use KML file, total size will become 150mb, which is a lot too much for just displaying a layer on a map... I can split KMZ files so that KML file becomes less than 3MB, but then I'm afraid I will exceed the limit for number of KMZ files to be loaded in one site... Isn't it ?

Comment: One more questions is, why other files are working ? KML file are also about 5MB, but they work.
I'm about to think that file validation is totally random...

Comment: Given the information provided in your question, there is no way to tell (other than guessing).

Comment: How about comparing a file that is working with a file that is not ?
I tried to check content, it is similar and I even removed all HTML content that was included inside description tag of KML file.
Currently, the working file's KML size is bigger than not working one.

Working:
https://mega.nz/#!zswzxKIB!8YYyZseW8CakNr6Ws5qaSTcKkByn3tLNbBD2zw_wx_U

Not working:
https://mega.nz/#!3h5RFIST!0TzTAJi9_zMIy7_AYxgJD-YbYDpQKRnB-UpH3bnmyUg

Comment: I just noticed something important.
When adding revision to the file URL (e.g. domain.com/1.kmz?r=124), files that has fetch_error now become OK.
At the contrary, some files that was ok become FETCH_ERROR.
Does anyone knows why ?

Comment: That implies that Google is caching the FETCH_ERROR, so changing the URL might fix it if the file is OK, but the FETCH_ERROR was a glitch.

Comment: Yes I thought about that, but how can I guarantee that when the cache will expire, a FETCH_ERROR occur again ? (it appear to happen quite frequently). With all the tests I did I think it happens when Google take too much time to fetch the file, or when we try to fetch many files at the same time.

Comment: You might retry (with a different revision #) if you get a FETCH_ERROR for some limited number of retries (if it takes too many, then it is probably a real problem).  Once you have a "working" revision, keep it (until you change the file again).  Where are you hosting these files?  Perhaps a server upgrade, or hosting them on a CDN of some kind might make it more reliable.

Comment: As you wrote, it seems that problem was coming from server.
I uploaded KMZ files to S3 server, then problem was solved.
Thank you very much for you help ! I wish I could mark this answer as best answer but seems I don't have enough reputation. Thank you anyway.